# How to implement this equation in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I'm new to `numpy`, and trying to implement the following equation.

The equation has two parts, and should give a final value called Sigma.

the equation is taken from the paper as below image:
[image of the equation to provide the result of Sigma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8WGu.png)

I tried to implement it as below, but when running the code, the value c is giving **nan**

```
c = np.sqrt(np.log(2 / np.sqrt( 16 * delta + 1 ) -1 ))

sigma = (c + np.sqrt(np.square(c) + epsilon) ) * s / (epsilon * np.sqrt(2))
```

appreciate if you can advise on how to implement it in numpy

Comment: What is your values for `c`, `epsilon` and `delta`?

Comment: `np.sqrt( 16 * delta + 1 ) -1` should be in brackets. Otherwise `2 / np.sqrt( 16 * delta + 1 )` is something positive small and `-1` makes it negative which goes to `log`. And `log` does not like negative values

Comment: This is either a typo (I'm assuming OP knows about order of operations), or a "needs debugging details", since no inputs are provided.

Comment: @Ananda thanks for the follow up, I'm using a fixed value of 0.02 for delta and trying several values for epsilon ranging from 0.1 to 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a bracket in your code

```
c = np.sqrt(np.log(2 / (np.sqrt( 16 * delta + 1 ) -1 )))

sigma = (c + np.sqrt(np.square(c) + epsilon) ) * s / (epsilon * np.sqrt(2))
```

To get a valid c value, you should input delta like 0 < delta < 0.5.

Comment: what delta value are you using for example?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a parenthesis. This is the correct formula:

```
c = np.sqrt(np.log(2/(np.sqrt(16*delta + 1) -1)))
```

Also, keep in mind that (as the paper states) this is defined only for [image: eq1].